# Unreadable html table data to List

Tags: java, list, selenium

I'm trying to read data off this table iteratively row by row. Somehow, I either end up failing to find the web element, or if it works fine, the objects do not get stored to the List (get to know while attempting to read 0th item - returns arrayindexoutofbounds exception). My HTML (more of a sample looks like this-

```
<div class="g1 sgs">
<table class="c67 bt dc " cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   style="position:absolute;top:25px;left:17px;" cols="16" idref="2.7" bid="7">
    <colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height:67px;" type="header">
            <td> ....
        <tr style="height:24px;">
            <td>....
        <tr style="height:24px;">
            <td>....
</div>
```

This is how I try to read this table (also tried with xpath, id and different combinations)-

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[class='c67 bt dc']"));
    System.out.println(" Test Data :: " + elements.get(0)); // returns arrayIndexOutOfBounds
    for (Iterator<WebElement> iterator = elements.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        WebElement webElement = iterator.next();
```

My purpose is to read each row of a particular column (Date data) and compare for validation.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[class='c67 bt dc']"));` returns an empty collection.

This means your locator is wrong or the elements are not visible & present on the screen when you think they are.

Having a quick look, I can see a trailing whitespace at the end of your class name:

```
<table class="c67 bt dc ">
```

So this CSS selector:

```
table[class='c67 bt dc']
```

is only going to match if the `table`'s `class` property is *exactly* **equal** to `c67 bt dc`. It isn't. It's *exactly* **equal** to `c67 bt dc` (note the extra whitespace)

Although, without prior knowledge of your webpage, it's difficult to know if these class names are actually static and are the best way to "get" your table element. Nonetheless, there are many ways to do it, but concentrating *just* on CSS selectors:

You could use either:

```
table.c67.bt.dc
```

or, being a little more "loose" on matching on *exact* class names:

```
table.c67
```

or even:

```
table[class*='c67 bt dc']
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried few of those. Now a another exception - arrayIndexOutOfBounds is thrown. I assume something has been read in that case but not recorded as an array. This happens when I'm trying to get even the 0th element from the list.